I want to only extract the content of li without the contents of span in Python Selenium WebDriver
So here is the sample html doc:
<div id="div1">
    <ul class="lists">
        <li class="listItem1"> List content 
            <span class="span1">span text</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

I only want to extract "List content"
If I do this:
elementList = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/div/ul/li")
elementList.text  

I get : List content span text
If I do this:
elementList = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/div/ul/li[1]")

I still get  List content span text
What can I do to only get
"List content" without the span text

Does this answer your question? Getting text from a node

@SiebeJongebloed That dup target is Java, not python.

elementList = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@class='listItem1']").text
span_text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='span1']").text
elementList = elementList.replace(span_text, "")

This might be a little long winded, but I think it should do the trick.

You're going to need a .strip() in there as well. I would use CSS selectors because they're faster, the syntax is shorter and easier to read, etc. For example, li.listItem1 and span.span1.
